# how to save texts written in different tabs?

Tags: java, swing

When i open two or more tabs and make changes with the text in those files and then , when i try to save those files ,first file is saved with the correct text while all other file got saved with the same text as that of the first selected file

```
public void saveFile() {
    int a1 = jtp.getSelectedIndex();
    File filepath1 = vec.elementAt(a1);
    File file1 = filepath1.getParentFile();
    String name = filepath1.getName();

    int pos = name.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (pos>0) {
        name = name.substring(0, pos);
    }

    File sfile = filepath1;

    JTextArea jt = (JTextArea)sc.getViewport().getView();
    strh = jt.getText();
    System.out.println(strh);       
    a=strh.toCharArray();

    System.out.println(sfile);          

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sfile);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            fos.write(a[i]);
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        System.out.print("File was not able to save");
    }           
}
```

Comment: when i open two or more tabs and make changes with the text in those files and then , when i try to save those files ,first file is saved with the correct text while all other file got saved with the same text as that of  the first selected file.

Comment: the code is not giving the correct result.

Comment: provide an executable sample code, otherwise its very difficult to understand your issue

Comment: Well, the text you write to the file comes from the `jt` text area, so you should make sure that this variable does not point to the same text field for each tab.